# Is the interior of a Jordan curve a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, borel-sets

A Jordan curve is a continuous closed curve in the plane with no self-intersections.  My question is, is the interior of a Jordan curve always a Borel set?

If not, is the interior of a convex Jordan curve at least a Borel set.  I know that convex sets need not be Borel sets, but maybe the combination implies Borel.

If not, does anyone know of a counterexample?

Comment: The interior is open – isn't every open set a Borel set?

Comment: What do you mean by interior? If it's in the topological sense then of course since every open set is a Borel set, as @MartinR points out. If you mean the set 'enclosed' by the Jordan curve then it's not so obvious.

Comment: Your choice of the word "interior" is a tad unfortunate, as indicated in the comment of @TonyS.F. To avoid this, topologists sometimes refer simply to the "inside" and "outside" of a Jordan curve.

Comment: @LeeMosher What is the difference between the interior of a Jordan curve and the “inside” of a Jordan curve?

Comment: @TonyS.F. Can you explain the difference between the set enclosed and the topological interior?

Comment: [Topological interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_point)

Comment: @LeeMosher I’m aware of what a topological interior is, but what is the set enclosed and how does it differ from the topological interior?

Comment: Take a look at the statement of the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem). You will see there the terms "interior" and "exterior" used in a way which clearly has nothing to do with the [topological interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)#Interior_point), which is why from a linguistic point of view I have proffered the advice to avoid the terms "interior" and "exterior"..

Comment: @LeeMosher So to be clear, are you saying that the “inside” connected component of the complement of a Jordan curve need not be an open set?

Comment: Certainly the inside of the Jordan curve is an open set. But the inside of the Jordan curve is disjoint from the Jordan curve itself. So it's not contained in the topological interior of the Jordan curve.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, that point is clear.  I just thought that Tony S.F’s statement “if you mean the set ‘enclosed’ by the Jordan curve then it’s not so obvious” suggested that something less trivial than an open set was involved.

Comment: I did not take Tony S.F.'s comment to be quite so trivial. The answer provided by @MartinR is pretty short, but not quite trivial.

Comment: @LeeMosher It seems pretty trivial to me, but if that’s all there is to this issue I’ll accept Martin’s answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan My comment was not trivial at all. Your question was ill posed and ambiguous because *you* misused the word interior, which has a precise mathematical meaning. The interior of Jordan curve is the empty set. Full stop. The bounded connected component of the complement of a Jordan curve (what you *mistakenly* called the interior) is something completely different and is a Borel set. Your comments suggest that you don't understand what a Jordan curve, or even the topological interior, is.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I do understand it, I was just being a bit loose with my language.

Comment: The fact that you ask, "Can you explain the difference between the set enclosed and the topological interior? " suggests you don't understand it, as they are two completely distinct sets. If you understand what the topological interior is then there is no confusion about the difference between it and the set enclosed by the Jordan curve.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I thought you meant something more sophisticated than the “inside” connected component of the complement, something that wasn’t an open set and thus something for which it wasn’t so obvious whether it was Borel or not.  Anyway sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The image of a Jordan curve is a compact set, so that its complement is open.
- The interior of the Jordan curve is one of the two connected components of that complement, and therefore open as well.
- Every open set is a Borel set.